# Passing an id to layout on Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Hello how can I pass an id to my layout file ?

with composer method I can pass variable and data.
but I just wanna pass an id which comes from

```
Route::get('markalar/{id}','HomeController@markalar');
```

I have tried something like

```
View::composer(array('home.markalar_layout'), function($view) 
 {
  return $view->with('referans', Reklam::find($id);;
 });
```

that but it didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still pass the parameter in the view composer.

Delcare the route:

```
Route::get('markalar/{id}','HomeController@markalar');
```

Compose the layout:

```
View::composer(array('home.markalar_layout'), function($view) 
{
      $id = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('id');
      $view->id = $id;
      $view->referans = Reklam::find($id);
});
```

Also, I don't think returning the view in the composer changes anything. I've tested it and it's all the same. Data set to the view in the composer is retained.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Other answers rely on with method and not composer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like:

```
Route::get('markalar/{id}','HomeController@markalar');
```

And in your controller:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

public function markalar($id)
{
    //Do what you need with $id

    //Build the view 
    return View::make('home.markalar_layout', array('id' => $id));
}

}
```